# Disable onclick function, in order to stop calling same function when an ajax on it is in progress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable onclick function, in order to stop calling same function when an ajax on it is in progress.

onclick function :

```
function fnDisplaySubjects(url,cat,divid)
{
    /* DISABLE ONCLICK HERE */
        $.ajax({
            url: url+"/cat/"+cat,
            type: "POST",
            complete: function(){
             /* ENABLE ONCLICK HERE */
        },
            success: function(response){
                $('#'+divid).html(response);        
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

Appreciate your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function fnDisplaySubjects(url,cat,divid, obj /* this object */)
{
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.data('called')) {
    return;
}
$this.data('called', true);
        $.ajax({
            url: url+"/cat/"+cat,
            type: "POST",
            complete: function(){
             /* ENABLE ONCLICK HERE */
        },
            success: function(response){
                $('#'+divid).html(response);  
                $this.removeData('called');      
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a sender (i.e button or link) and do like this:

```
$(sender).attr('disabled', true); // to disable
....
$(sender).attr('disabled', false); // to enable
```

Comment: tried this but doesn't work, still calls function multiple times

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button and on clicking it that function is called, you can do:

// Remove click handler (what you call /* DISABLE ONCLICK HERE */)

```
$('#button_id').off('click');
```

// Set click handler (what you call /* ENABLE ONCLICK HERE */

```
$('#button_id').on('click', fnDisplaySubjects);
```